# Asp.Net Core - Use getJSON for get data from Razor page control?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

I have two select lists. I want to get information from the database when the first select list is selected?

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <label class="">Main Category</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="maincategory" asp-items="@ViewData["MainCategory"] as SelectList">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <label class="">First Sub</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="ParentId" asp-for="CategoryModel.ParentId" asp-items="@ViewData["FirstSubCategory"] as SelectList">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript Ajax :

```
 $("#maincategory").change(function () {
        $("#ParentId").empty();
        @*rl:"@Url.Page(pageName: "Details", pageHandler: "Send", values: new { id = Model.Exercise.ID }"*@ 
        let maincat = $("#maincategory :selected").val();
        $.getJSON("/AdminPanel/Category/AddAndEditSecondSubCategory?handler=GetSubCategory/" + maincat ,
            function (data) {
                $.each(data,
                    function () {
                        $("#ParentId").append('<option value= ' + this.value + '>' + this.text + '</option>');
                    })
            }

        )
    });
```

Razor Control :

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(Guid id, Guid mainid, Guid firstid, byte level)
    {
        if (level == 1)//Add
        {
            CategoryModel = new CategoryViewModel();
            CategoryModel.Id = id;
            return Page();
        }
        else
        {
            var category = await admin.GetCategoryById(id);

            var categories = await admin.GetCategories();
            MainCategories = new SelectList(categories.Where(c => c.ParentId == null), "Id", "CategoryName",mainid);
            FirstSubCategory = new SelectList(categories.Where(c => c.ParentId == mainid), "Id", "CategoryName", firstid);
            CategoryModel = new CategoryViewModel();
            CategoryModel.Id = category.Id;
            CategoryModel.CategoryName = category.CategoryName;
            CategoryModel.ParentId = category.ParentId;
            CategoryModel.Level = level;
           // Categories = new SelectList(await admin.GetCategories(), nameof(Category.Id), nameof(Category.CategoryName));
            return Page();
        }

    }

 public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsyncGetSubCategory(Guid id)
    {
        var SubCategory_List = await admin.GetCategories();
        return new JsonResult(new SelectList(SubCategory_List.Where(c => c.ParentId == id), "Id", "CategoryName"));
    }
```

I have another onget action in the same controller...
When I select the item and break point, it enters the first action.

Comment: Your code looks correct, can you tell us what the problem is? If you mean after select the first DropDown List, the second DropDown List is empty, you could set a break point to check whether the id is correct or not? Then, check the data in the `ViewData["MainCategory"]`.

Comment: When I select the list and break point, it enters another action.Because I have two onget actions

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

> I have another onget action in the same controller... When I select
> the item and break point, it enters the first action.

Do you mean after select the Main Category, it will not calling the OnGetAsyncGetSubCategory handler method?

The issue might relates the request url:

> ```
> $.getJSON("/AdminPanel/Category/AddAndEditSecondSubCategory?handler=GetSubCategory/" + maincat ,
> ```

To add the parameter, the request url should like this: `?handler=GetSubCategory&id=" + maincat`

Try to use the following code:

```
  $.getJSON("/AdminPanel/Category/AddAndEditSecondSubCategory?handler=GetSubCategory&id=" + maincat ,
            function (data) {
                $.each(data,
                    function () {
                        $("#ParentId").append('<option value= ' + this.value + '>' + this.text + '</option>');
                    })
            }

        )
```

**Original Reply**

From your code and description, it seems that you want to create a Cascading Dropdowns With AJAX in Razor Pages. In this scenario, you could refer the following code:

Code in the .cshtml.cs file: In this sample, it will get the data from the ICategoryService, you can change it to DbContext, then get value from database.

```
public class CascadingDropdownsModel : PageModel
{
    private ICategoryService categoryService;
    public CascadingDropdownsModel(ICategoryService categoryService) => this.categoryService = categoryService;
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public SelectList Categories { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        //get the category data, and popuplate the first dropdown list.
        Categories = new SelectList(categoryService.GetCategories(), nameof(Category.CategoryId), nameof(Category.CategoryName));
    }
    public JsonResult OnGetSubCategories()
    {
        //based on the categoryid to find all subcategories, then return them to the view page and populate the second dropdownlist.
        return new JsonResult(categoryService.GetSubCategories(CategoryId));
    }
}
```

Code in the .csthml file:

```
@page
@model RazorAPP.Pages.CascadingDropdownsModel
<h4>Categories</h4>
<select asp-for="CategoryId" asp-items="Model.Categories">
    <option value="">Select Category</option>
</select>
<h4>SubCategories</h4>
<select asp-for="SubCategoryId"></select>

@section scripts{ 
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#CategoryId").on("change", function() {
            var categoryId = $(this).val();
            $("#SubCategoryId").empty();
            $("#SubCategoryId").append("<option value=''>Select SubCategory</option>");
            $.getJSON(`?handler=SubCategories&categoryId=${categoryId}`, (data) => {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    $("#SubCategoryId").append(`<option value="${item.subCategoryId}">${item.subCategoryName}</option>`);
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

The result like this:

[image]

More detail information, see [Cascading Dropdowns With AJAX in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/cascading-dropdowns).

Comment: thanks,I edited my questions and put the get action

Comment: Hi @sunboy_sunboy, Please check the update, the issue might relates the request url and parameter.